# Absolute convergence of sum and convergence to $0$ of product imply that at least one term in the product is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I'm trying to understand infinite products, and one of the sources I'm reading through says (without proof) that if $\sum |a_n|$ converges and $\prod (1+a_n)=0$ then $a_k=-1$ for some $k$. Why is this true?

Comment: If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$. Which would imply $\prod (1+a_n)=1$, unless at least one $a_k = -1$.

Comment: @StevenGregory How about $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then $a_n\rightarrow 0$ but $\prod (1+a_n)\neq 1$

Comment: Yes you are right. Should I delete the comment?

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}|a_{n}|$$converges
means $$a_{n}$$goes to zero
so if $$\prod(1+a_{n})$$ goes to zero
then $$ln(\prod(1+a_{n}))=\sum ln(1+a_{n})$$
does not converge but since $$a_{n}$$ goes to zero$$ln(1+a_{n})$$ goes to zero but that would imply that the sum $$\sum ln(1+a_{n})$$ converges but we just know it can't and the only way this is possible is if one of the $$a_{n}$$ is -1 since $$ln(1-1)=ln(0)=\inf$$

Comment: Actually the convergence of $$a_{n}$$ is more information than needed. That the product is zero must mean than one of the $$a_{n}$$ is -1 regardless.